# Как найти минимальный элемент в multimap?

Tags: c++

Получается только обозначить MIN как огромное число, но пользователь то может превысить его.
Знаю, что решение на поверхности, но не могу понять, как это делается. Нужно найти минимальное значение в MULTIMAPe, только не задавая огромное число, а вот например присвоить переменной MIN 1 элемент multimapa.
Можно ли так сделать, если да, то как?

```
    float MIN(multimap<int, float>& map)
    {
        float MIN;
        for (const auto& num : map)
        {
            if (MIN >= num.second)
            {
                MIN = num.second;
            }
        }
        return MIN;
    }
```

Comment: Может вам держать еще контейнер float -> int? Если поиск требуется производиться часто, то это будет куда быстрее, чем шерстить весь контейнер целиком каждый раз, как того насоветовали в ответах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно не просто задать огромное число, а нужно задать максимальное для данного типа:

```
float MIN = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
```

Но проще воспользоваться алгоритмом стандартной библиотеки:

```
auto min_it = std::min_element(map.begin(), map.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
    return a.second < b.second;
});

if (min_it != map.end()) {
    cout << "min_element: " << min_it->second << endl;
} else {
    cout << "map is empty" << endl;
}
```

Comment: проверку на пустоту стоит выполнить в  начале:  if (!map.empty())  , тогда и писать меньше и не будет выполнен лишний код

Comment: Но ведь у `float` есть значение, которое больше, чем `std::numeric_limits<float>::max()` :)

Answer (score 2):

Раз вас все равно интересует значение, а не ключ...

```
auto * min_iter = min_element(m.begin(),m.end(),
                              [](auto a, auto b) { return a.second < b.second;});
```

Например, так. Получите итератор, указывающий на наименьший элемент (или первый из них).

Comment: у вас там вместо `;` `'` поправьте

Comment: @SKIP Спасибо, уже.